# Neo4j Cypher order nodes by dependencies

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Nodes tree structure, for example:

```
(n1:Node)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(n2:Node)
(n4:Node)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(n2:Node)
(n5:Node)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(n1:Node)
(n5:Node)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(n4:Node)
```

I may have any such combinations where one Node depends on another.

How do I write the Cypher query to return all :Node lists ordered by their dependencies, so that the least dependent ones come first?

Additionally, is it possible to handle cyclical dependencies with a Cypher query and fail the query in such cases?

Comment: Using you example data, are you expecting one row per node with a list of dependencies? Or one row with all reachable nodes on it, ordered like so: `[2, 1, 4, 5]`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  As the result I just expect a properly ordered list of nodes, for example in case of example data: `n2, n1, n4, n5`. So one row should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the count of dependencies is the number of distinct nodes that can be reached by `-[:DEPENDS_ON]->`. So here's a suggestion:

```cypher
// Raise an exception if a cycle is found
CALL apoc.util.validate(
    EXISTS { (n:Node)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->+(n) }, 
    'Cyclical dependencies exists', 
    [0]
)

// Find all leaves connected to each other
// The first two NOT EXISTS check for leaves
// The third NOT EXISTS removes duplicates
MATCH (a:Node)-[:DEPENDS_ON]-*(b:Node)
WHERE NOT EXISTS { (a)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(:Node) }
    AND NOT EXISTS { (b)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(:Node) }
    AND a <= b
    AND NOT EXISTS { 
            MATCH (a)-[:DEPENDS_ON]-+(c:Node) 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS { (c)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(:Node) } 
            AND c < a 
        }
WITH a, collect(DISTINCT b) AS connectedLeaves

// Find all nodes connected to those sets of leaves 
// a is the group key, so each disconnected dependency graph is kept separate
UNWIND a + connectedLeaves AS leaf
MATCH (n:Node)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->*(leaf)
WITH a, collect(DISTINCT n) AS connected

// Collect into list ordered by number of dependencies
RETURN COLLECT {
    WITH connected
    UNWIND connected AS n
    MATCH (n:Node)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->*(t:Node)
    WITH n, count(DISTINCT t) AS numDependencies
    RETURN n ORDER BY numDependencies
} AS connectedDependencies;
```

Results with your example data:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| connectedDependencies                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [(:Node {id: 2}), (:Node {id: 4}), (:Node {id: 1}), (:Node {id: 5})] |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```